# Swift MailCore2 GTMAppAuth Allowing Less Secure App Access

Tags: swift, google-api, mailcore2

I am building a test app using MailCore2 and GTMAppAuth, and I bumped into this error:

> A stable connection to the server could not be established.

I followed various SO posts, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237397/gtmappauth-mailcore-a-stable-connection-to-the-server-could-not-be-establish), [this](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth) and [this](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/wiki/Implementing-OAuth-2.0), and so I think my code should be correct. My implementation are as follows:

```
//At AppDelegate
var currentAuthorizationFlow: OIDAuthorizationFlowSession?

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
{
    if currentAuthorizationFlow!.resumeAuthorizationFlow(with: url) {
        self.currentAuthorizationFlow = nil
        return true
    }
    return false
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let kIssuer = "https://accounts.google.com"
    let kClientID = "\(MY_CLIENTID).apps.googleusercontent.com"
    let kRedirectURI = "com.googleusercontent.apps\(MY_CLIENTID):/oauthredirect"
    let kExampleAuthorizerKey = "googleOAuthCodingKey"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authenticateGmail()
    }

    func authenticateGmail() {
        let issuer = URL(string: kIssuer)!
        let redirectURI = URL(string: kRedirectURI)!
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        OIDAuthorizationService.discoverConfiguration(forIssuer: issuer) { (configuration, error) in
            //handleError

            if let configuration = configuration {
                let scopes = [OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile, "https://mail.google.com/"]
                let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration, clientId: self.kClientID, scopes: scopes, redirectURL: redirectURI, responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode, additionalParameters: nil)

                appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self, callback: { (authState, error) in
                    //handleError

                    if let authState = authState {
                        if let accessToken = authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken {
                            NSLog("Successfully authenticated: %@", accessToken)
                            self.fetchEmailsFromGmail(accessToken: accessToken)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchEmailsFromGmail(accessToken: String) {
        let session = MCOIMAPSession()
        session.hostname = "imap.gmail.com"
        session.port = 993
        session.username = "XXX@\(COMPANY_DOMAIN)"
        session.authType = .xoAuth2
        session.connectionType = .TLS
        session.oAuth2Token = accessToken

        let fetchFolderOperation = session.fetchAllFoldersOperation()
        fetchFolderOperation?.start({ (error, folders) in
            //handleError

            if let folders = folders, !folders.isEmpty {
                print(folders)
            }
        })
    }
```

My implementation allows me to authenticate successfully, ie there is an `accessToken` printed. But when it attempts to fetch folders, it throws:

> A stable connection to the server could not be established.

The thing is, it is possible to solve this by doing both the following:

1. allowing less secure app access via the Googles Accounts page
2. follow this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982176/error-when-im-using-mailcore2-in-swift-2)

However, these methods are not really safe methods in my opinion. I do not recall needing to do any of these when I connect up my email to other email clients, ie Outlook etc, so I do not view the above as real solutions.

Could anyone advice? Is there something wrong with my code, or I really have to resort to doing both steps above?

Comment: any advice here?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I am in the exact same situation...

Comment: @Daniel unfortunately I did not. One of the possible reasons that my ex-colleague (I have already moved on to other projects) had suggested back then was that because we were calling google apis from behind a VPN. That resulted from that unstable connection, which came periodically.